# PHP : How to push key/value pair with a loop?

Tags: php, arrays

Good morning all,

I've a nested array and I've found a way to print it.
But I need to convert it into a more simple array, in order to export it in a .csv at last.

1.First, my json result comes as nested array like this (there's much more sub arrays in fact) :

```
["DATA"=>[
    0["ID"=>"123456789",
      "STORE"=>[0["NAME"=>"my store ","STREET"=>"baker street" ]]],
    1["ID"=>"987654321",
      "STORE"=>[0["NAME"=>"the last irish pub","STREET"=>"Endov Daworld Street",]]]]]
```

2.and with the function's code from Mr Tran Duc Thang (thanks a lot) 
I'm able to print it. But I've try to re use his code in order to create more simple array like this :

```
Array(
    0("ID"=>"123465789","Name"=>"my store",...),
    1("ID"=>"987654321","Name"=>"the last irish pub",...))
```

3.the code :

```
$dest_array = array();
class Foo {
    public static function formatArray($arr){
        foreach ($arr as $key=> $value){
            if(is_array($value)) {
                if(!empty($value)) {
                     self::formatArray($value);
                }
            } else {    
                    $dest_array[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

Foo::formatArray($json_decoded); 

foreach($dest_array as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k => $val";
}
```

`var_dum($dest_array)` shows me the array is empty `array (size = 0)`

I've try to use `array_push` instead of `$dest_array[$key] = $value`
but it doesn't work too.

What I have missed? 
Have you any idea please?

Thanks

Comment: Its a scoping issue. $dest_array outside class Foo is different from inside method formatArray. If you want to alter the incoming array, you can pass in the $json_decoded as reference.

Comment: _“What I have miss?”_ - how important it is to configure your PHP error reporting properly for development purposes.

Comment: Typo: `$valeur` should be `$value`. Is that in the original code or a copying error?

Comment: if(is_array($value)) will this work? is $value an array?

Comment: You're not pushing multiple rows into your result array, you're just overwriting the named keys each time.

Comment: You have also a recurrence problem, when your `$value` is an array, you call `formatArray` but you do nothing with the result. Even if you want that your function transforms by reference, you just go to the next row after formatting

Comment: 1. About scope : okay. Sorry I've re write the code so many times that I forgot it

Comment: 2. @Barman : no I've change some name cause my original code doesn't use english name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least 3 problems with your code:

- First, when `$value` is an array, you format it, but do nothing with the result
- You try to act with recursion, but you have 2 steps that behave differently: for the arrays directly inside "DATA", you want to keep the arrays distinct, but for what's inside them you want to "flatten" them, meaning that latter keys would replace existing ones, if you go full recursion, you'll have only one set of results instead of your 2 that are in the example
- You try to modify by rerence and have a new array for the result, these are 2 different approaches.

the modified code - it's calling the formatter on each line of your result (or else the recursive function would merge the 2 stores):

```
$json_decoded = [
    "DATA" => [
        ["ID"=>"123456789", "STORE"=> [ ["NAME"=>"my store ", "STREET"=>"baker street"] ] ],
        ["ID"=>"987654321", "STORE"=> [ ["NAME"=>"the last irish pub", "STREET"=>"Endov Daworld Street"] ] ],
    ],
]; 

class Foo {
    public static function formatArray($arr){
        $dest_array = [];
        foreach ($arr as $key=> $value){
            if(is_array($value)) {
                if(!empty($value)) {
                    foreach(self::formatArray($value) as $key2=> $value2){
                        $dest_array[$key2] = $value2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $dest_array[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $dest_array;
    }
}

foreach($json_decoded['DATA'] as $k => $v) {
    $v = Foo::formatArray($v);
    foreach($v as $k2 => $v2) {
        echo "$k2 => $v2 <br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: (-_-) Jeez ! I've a lot to learn.Thanks @Kaddath. I gonna read and try to understand each point and then, apply the code.

Comment: OKAY  \(^o^)/ 
Honestly I've never think about this : *foreach(self::formatArray($value) as $key2=> $value2)*        I've read the code 4 times and now it seem totally clear and simple :D

Comment: THANKS EVERYBODY FOR YOUR HELP. I'VE LEARN A LOT TODAY WITH ALL OF YOU !!  :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion, just nested loops. The outer loop processes the `DATA` array, the inner loop processes the `STORE` arrays.

```
$dest_array = array();
foreach ($json_decoded['DATA'] as $data) {
    $id = $data['ID'];
    foreach ($data['STORE'] as $store) {
        $store['ID'] = $id;
        $dest_array[] = $store;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I gonna try it

Answer (score 0):

Your function has no access on the global scope where your variable is. you have 2 options for this - either with global scope (in general bad)

```
class Foo {
    public static function formatArray($arr){
        global $dest_array; // <<< makes it available
        foreach ($arr as $key=> $value){
            if(is_array($value)) {
                if(!empty($value)) {
                     self::formatArray($value);
                }
            } else {    
                    $dest_array[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or as a better solution to return your new structure with a base array (no global dependency then!)

```
class Foo {
    public static function formatArray($arr, $base = []){
        foreach ($arr as $key=> $value){
            if(is_array($value)) {
                if(!empty($value)) {
                     $base = self::formatArray($value, $base);
                }
            } else {    
                    $base[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $base;
    }
}

$dest_array = Foo::formatArray($json_decoded);
```

Comment: so the second code works well :) but I've to re adapt it cause the the last key / value pairs overwrite the previous pairs. thanks a lot @wodka